# New residential toilets all so tall?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, code-compliance

Are all new toilets high off the ground?  Our existing toilets (one 20-year-old Toto and one ancient 5 GPF monster that I am shopping to replace) are around 14.5" from the floor to the rim of the bowl.  But all the toilets I've looked at online (from Kohler, American Standard, etc.) seem to be at least 16" high.

We are looking for a 14" rough-in toilet so is that the reason why they're all so tall?

I know some people like the higher height but we prefer the height of our existing toilets.  Is there a modern brand and model that is similar to our existing "low-rider" porcelain thrones?  If new toilets are all taller, is there a brand and model that's less tall than the others?

Also, I know there are ADA compliance heights for commercial toilets, but for single-family residential (in California) are there also likely to be code requirements governing toilet heights?

Answer (score 1):

There are still [toilets with bowl heights of 14.5 - 15.5"](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Bath-Toilets-Toilet-Seats-Bidets-Toilets/145-155/N-5yc1vZbzbdZ2bcu0d?NCNI-5). It seems as though Kohler (among others), like to advertise their "*Comfort height™*" toilets. However, they do offer toilets in all height ranges.

- Standard height: 14 1/2" - 15 1/2"
- "Comfort height": 16" - 17"
- ADA Compliant: 17" - 19"

Answer (score 0):

California has not decided to regulate and tax toilet height yet but its only a matter of time.
What they do regulate is gallons per flush. Assembly Bill 715 says that as of Jan. 1st 2014 it is illegal for manufacturers to sell toilets that exceed 1.28 GPF in California.

This, along with the 14" rough-in requirement, is limiting your selection, in fact: Kohler only makes [one style of toilet](http://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1151864_4.pdf) that will meet your requirements.

Comment: That document shows a bowl height of 14 1/2", which is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Start bootlegging toilets from Nevada.